# Пожалуйста, кто может объяснить в чем смысл get b set в данном примере?

Tags: vue.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста, кто может объяснить в чем смысл get b set  в данном примере ? Буду благодарен за пример!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё просто. Может быть десяток мест кода, где нужно использовать связку  `Имя Фамилия`. И каждый раз писать такую связку через конкатенацию будет сложно и нудно. А если вдруг захочется между ИФ поставить не пробел, а подчёркивание- то придётся везде заменять эти участки кода. В данном случае это нужно для упрощения и, чтобы в коде выводить связку `Имя Фамилия` обращаясь к методу, который уже делает необходимую прописанную работу.

С сетером примерно тоже самое, только наоборот. Например если есть одно поле для ввода, какая-нибудь форма и даже не одна, то её итог будет разбиваться в коде на отдельные переменные для дальнейшего оперирования ими